# Undertow blocking operations with dispatch is not working

Tags: undertow

I can't get the very basic Undertow example to work as expected. The following code should allow concurrent HTTP requests to be served. What actually happens, is that only one request is processed and no other requests can get through until the first one is completed.

```
public class MainUT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Undertow.builder()                                                      
            .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")                                    
            .setHandler(new HttpHandler() {                                                   
                @Override
                public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) 
                                            throws Exception {
                    if(exchange.isInIoThread()){
                        exchange.dispatch(this);
                        return;
                    }
                    exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain");
                    exchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World");               
                }
            }).build().start();
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

I used Chrome to do a GET request and paused the debugger after the request is dispatched. Then issued a `curl` command

```
 curl http://localhost:8080
```

The curl command only returns after the Chrome request is completely served.

I test that on both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` listeners.

Increasing the XNIO threads number and their workers does not change anything. A random XNIO is assigned to the request. Then a random worker is assigned after dispatching. The server remains blocked until the request is served.

Comment: Your code looks okay. Any errors? Behavior? How did you test it? What is your HTTP client?

Comment: No error. When issuing GET request from Chrome, it blocks any other requests until it is finished.

Comment: Does your browser get busy? How are you simultaneous requests?

Comment: You should try [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to test it for concurrent requests. Because, browser sends only one request at a time. You cannot send multiple requests from the browser.

Comment: I used a browser and `curl` command from bash. Same result.

Comment: `curl` in a loop? Can you post your command?

Comment: There you have it. When you `pause` the debugger, it is doing what it is supposed to do. It pauses the execution to let you observe the current state of the application. Just let it run and then perform regression testing using JMeter or using `curl` from two or more different terminals in a loop.

Comment: I am pausing only one thread. The server should be able to accept and process any other HTTP request.

Comment: And, it is **NOT** the main thread that is accepting the incoming requests?

Comment: thanks @Azeem ! 
I didn't know that we cannot send multiple requests from the browser

Comment: @frhack: You're welcome! It needs some clarification though. With one browser **tab**, you can send only one request. If the server can handle multiple requests simultaneously, you may open another tab and make another request. Given the fact that the OP was testing it manually and you can hit one URL at a time. Hope it would make sense given the complete context here.

Answer (score 1):

You code looks ok but looking at [BlockingHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/BlockingHandler.java#L52) try the following or use BlockingHandler directly.

```
exchange.startBlocking();
if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
    exchange.dispatch(handler);
} else {
    handler.handleRequest(exchange);
}
```

For an easy way to chain HttpHandlers look at [MiddlewareBuilder](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/logging-gzip-blocking-exception-handling-metrics-middleware-chaining-in-undertow#middleware). I would also try setting up the access logging handler so you can see what is going on and which thread is handling each request.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks for the answer. I had already tried `BlockingHandler` It did not work as well. I can see the request is handled by another thread but the whole server is not able to accept any more requests. I will follow your other suggestions.

Comment: Could you give the exact example that is not working? Are you using a sleep or something along those lines to test?

Comment: If you are using the debugger in the IDE wouldn't it pause both threads at the same point? Making you think it's waiting but really both threads just hit the debug statement.

Comment: The exact example that is not working is the one in the question. I will update the question with screenshots showing how requests are blocked until the first one is served

Comment: Even without using a blocking handler undertow runs with more than one IO thread so you should be able to handle at the very least 2-4 requests at once. Seems like something is up with the debugger.